# Why post request is working on local machine but in EC2 machine fails?

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, http-post

When I am trying to do a post request in my remote machine through the view file presented below I'm getting an HTTP 400 bad request, however, when I do the same using my local machine it works perfectly.

**Remote machine (Using docker on an EC2 machine)**

- django == 2.2.1
- drf == 3.9.4
- python == 3.7

> serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import irrigation, moisture

class IrrigationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = irrigation
        fields = '__all__'
```

> views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.urls import reverse

    from .models import irrigation, moisture
    from .serializers import IrrigationSerializer

    from rest_framework import viewsets
    from rest_framework import status
    from rest_framework.response import Response
    from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, action

    class irrigationValues(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = irrigation.objects.all()
        serializer_class = IrrigationSerializer

        def list(self, request):
            serializer = self.serializer_class(self.queryset, many = True)
            return Response(serializer.data)

    def dashboard(request):
        irrigations = irrigation.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'dashboard.html',{'irrigations':irrigations})

    @api_view(['POST'])
def addIrrigation(request):
    addIrrigation = IrrigationSerializer(data=request.data)
    print(request.data)
    if addIrrigation.is_valid():
        addIrrigation.save()
        return Response({"data":"Value added"},status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        error_details = []
        for key in addIrrigation.errors.keys():
            error_details.append({"field": key, "message": addIrrigation.errors[key][0]})
        data = {
                "Error": {
                    "status": 400,
                    "message": "Your submitted data was not valid - please correct the below errors",
                    "error_details": error_details
                    }
                }
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**The result that I'm getting from the local machine is:**

```
{
    "data":"Value added"
}
```

The output from the "print(request.data)" is:

```
{'hardware_id': '001', 'temperature': 23, 'valve_status': 'Close'}
[02/Jul/2019 11:38:35] "POST /dashboard/addirrigation/ HTTP/1.1" 201 5680
```

**The result that I'm getting from the remote machine is:**

```
{
    "Error": {
        "status": 400,
        "message": "Your submitted data was not valid - please correct the below errors",
        "error_details": [
            {
                "field": "hardware_id",
                "message": "This field is required."
            },
            {
                "field": "temperature",
                "message": "This field is required."
            },
            {
                "field": "valve_status",
                "message": "This field is required."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The output from the "print(request.data)" is:

```
<QueryDict: {'_content_type': ['application/json'], '_content': ['{\r\n    "hardware_id": "001",\r\n    "temperature": 23,\r\n    "valve_status": "Close"\r\n}']}>Bad Request: /dashboard/addirrigation/
```

Note: Maybe this is obvious for you, but I need to mention that when I do a post request through the drf using the "HTML form" the post is committed successfully, nevertheless, it does not work when I use the "Raw data" option to post it.

[Picture of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBGzY.jpg)

Comment: Why are you using different versions in Dec l development and production? You should use the same.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm having issues trying to install python3 on the remote machine which would allow me to use django 2.2.1. I've try different methods to upgrade the python version, but none of them have worked.

Comment: But the remote machine is using docker! You don't need to install anything, just use an image based on python 3.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've created the django projet from the remote machine using django 1.11.20, python 2.7.

Comment: Yes you said that. But you should use the same version as in development. Since you are using docker, that should be simple.

Comment: The issue seems to be within your serializer which you didn't provide. Beside I second the point to use the same version both for Python and Django.

Comment: @DanielRoseman correct I'm using Docker, I have changed the environment to someone that I have in my local machine and still no work. Just in case.. I've created the django projet from the remote machine using django 1.11.20, python 2.7, I do not know if I'm having the error for that reason.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I think I'm getting closer, please observe the question update, particularly "The output from the print(request.data)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As demonstrated in the picture attached to the problem, when I tried to add the data through the API portal I received the HTTP 400 response, but when I used postman and selected the content type of the query as "application/json" the data was posted successfully (HTTP 201 response).

Comment: was your problem got resolved on AWS?